# Dask group by apply compute distance to reference table

Tags: pandas, numpy, dask

**Action**
Group by, apply, retrieve reference from other dataframe, for every value in group compute distance to reference.

**Problem**
Introduction of inexplicable NaN values, different results for different runs.

**Attempts**
Tried the computation of apply function (without group by) and works fine. So the problem does not seem to be in the computation.

**Question**
What is causing these NaN values and why is the computation different for multiple runs?

**Example**

Following example passes all assertions, but gives unexpected results

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[232126.703, 232126.674, 232126.650, 232126.644, 232126.966],
                    'y':[579530.01599999995,579530.05099999998,579530.09100000001,579530.15099999995,579530.23199999996], 
                    'z':[16858.0, 16878.0, 16904.0, 16950.0, 16973.0], 
                    'hash':[1,2,2,1,1],
                    'label':[3,5,3,5,3]})
df = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 2)

df_pos = pd.DataFrame({'x_c':[232124.703, 232127.674, 232126.650, 232126.644, 232126.966],
                    'y_c':[579533.01599999995,579531.05099999998,579530.09100000001,579530.15099999995,579530.23199999996], 
                    'hash':[1,2,3,4,5]})

def add_distance(df, df_pos=df_pos):
    ref = df_pos[df_pos.hash == df.name].copy()
    df = df.copy()
    assert df[['x', 'y']].values.shape[1] == ref[['x_c', 'y_c']].values.shape[1]
    assert ref[['x_c', 'y_c']].values.shape[1] == 2
    d_traj = np.linalg.norm(df[['x', 'y']].values - ref[['x_c', 'y_c']].values, axis=1)
    assert np.isnan(d_traj).any() == False
    d_traj = pd.Series(d_traj)
    assert len(d_traj) == len(df)
    df['d_traj'] = d_traj
    return df

df_traj = df.groupby('hash').apply(add_distance, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=['hash', 'label', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd_traj']))

df_traj.compute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case are the original indices of `df`. To prevent the `d_traj` overwrite itself multiple times and leave the other records with `NaN` values first use `reset_index()`.

**Example**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[232126.703, 232126.674, 232126.650, 232126.644, 232126.966],
                    'y':[579530.01599999995,579530.05099999998,579530.09100000001,579530.15099999995,579530.23199999996], 
                    'z':[16858.0, 16878.0, 16904.0, 16950.0, 16973.0], 
                    'hash':[1,2,2,1,1],
                    'label':[3,5,3,5,3]})
df = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 2)

df_pos = pd.DataFrame({'x_c':[232124.703, 232127.674, 232126.650, 232126.644, 232126.966],
                    'y_c':[579533.01599999995,579531.05099999998,579530.09100000001,579530.15099999995,579530.23199999996], 
                    'hash':[1,2,3,4,5]})

def add_distance(df, df_pos=df_pos):
    ref = df_pos[df_pos.hash == df.name].copy()
    df = df.copy()
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) # added this line!
    d_traj = np.linalg.norm(df[['x', 'y']].values - ref[['x_c', 'y_c']].values, axis=1)
    d_traj = pd.Series(d_traj)
    df['d_traj'] = d_traj
    return df

df_traj = df.groupby('hash').apply(add_distance, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=['hash', 'label', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd_traj']))

df_traj.compute()
```

Comment: Please note that if in your case `df_pos` is a Dask DataFrame as well, you will need to `.compute()` in `d_traj = np.linalg.norm(df[['x', 'y']].values - ref[['x_c', 'y_c']].values.compute(), axis=1)`